# Attach shipping information to Stripe Charge using Go

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a new charge via the Go API. I have a shipping address and a payment token. But [the Go API doesn't seem to support sending the shipping address](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/920787c2ce10072919778f060e344fdcebe8a3f3/charge.go#L15-L25). [The documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/go#create_charge) indicates that it should support it but there isn't a direct mapping between the arguments described in the docs and the Go `ChargeParams` arguments and some are missing.

```
type ChargeParams struct {
    Params
    Amount                 uint64
    Currency               Currency
    Customer, Token        string
    Desc, Statement, Email string
    NoCapture              bool
    Fee                    uint64
    Fraud                  FraudReport
    Source                 *SourceParams
}
```

Is there some other way that I'm supposed to add the address that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Stripe support.

> Thanks for writing in about this, I'm happy to help! Unfortunately our
>   go bindings don't support that parameter at the moment which is why
>   you couldn't find it in the source. The temporary solution would be to
>   create the POST request yourself when you need to send the shipping
>   details along with the charge.
>
> I've forwarded this internally to make sure it gets addressed in the
>   future but unfortunately I don't have any timeline to share with you
>   at the moment. We are definitely open to a Pull Request from one of
>   our users so if that's something you'd feel comfortable building
>   yourself that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Stripe's API but if you follow the fields of the struct, you find `Charge` ➜ `Source` ➜ `Card` ➜ `Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Country`. Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use `ChargeParams` to include shipping infomation https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/master/charge/client_test.go

```
charge, err := New(&stripe.ChargeParams{
    Amount:   stripe.Int64(11700),
    Currency: stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
    Source:   &stripe.SourceParams{Token: stripe.String("src_123")},
    Shipping: &stripe.ShippingDetailsParams{
        Address: &stripe.AddressParams{
            Line1: stripe.String("line1"),
            City:  stripe.String("city"),
        },
        Carrier: stripe.String("carrier"),
        Name:    stripe.String("name"),
    }
})
```